# Convert ArrayList of objects (Value, Key) values into TLV - Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, tlv

I have a data class called Tags that contains a key and value (both Strings). I am required to generate a TLV with these Tag entries but none of the libraries I have used have worked.

Primarily:

- https://github.com/evsinev/ber-tlv
- https://github.com/TapTrack/KotlinTLV

An example of a Tag we have is:

Tags("df79", "353533")

Does anyone know how to create a TLV with string data in this format? Do I misunderstand how TLV works? All the libraries require Int or ByteArray properties.

Comment: I don't think there is any kind of standard for creating TLV - this is just a concept and libraries can implement it differently. What is your expected output for above input?

Comment: @broot it is supposed to be 'DF7903353533'